# Ionrangeslider update value with previously set value

Tags: ion-range-slider

I am using ionRangeslider in one of my forms to show the range of tips.

How can I update the value on submit button click so that when next time page loads, it shows the slider with that particular updated value?

HTML code

```
<input type="text" class="exampleslider" id="exampleslider" name="tips">
```

And Calling to ionRangeSlider via js

```
$('.exampleslider').ionRangeSlider({
  from: 0,
  to: 100,
  min: 0,
  grid: true,
  grid_num: 10,
  step: 10,
  postfix: '%',
});
```

Input is given name tips through which I want to set its value via database.

Answer (score 20):

```
 var instance = $(id).data("ionRangeSlider");

 instance.update({
   from: 10 //your new value
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a slider with custom values.

In this case, the indices should be used as `from` `to` values instead of actual values.

For example, the slider was initialized with this array:

`[0, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 10000]`

Let update its handles to be on `500` and `2000`:

```
var data = $('#' + id).data("ionRangeSlider");

data.update({
   from: 2,
     to: 4 
 });
```